# Node.js how to find local node_modules folder from a globally installed package

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm writing my own CLI node module 'npak' that is installed globally.

I need to find the absolute path of the local 'node_modules' folder of a project where the (the global) cli command was executed.

say the project looks like this:

```
/home
  /projects
    /test-project/
      /package.json
      /node-modules
      /folder-one
         /folder-two
            /folder-three/ npak find-modules 
                            ^-- this should return absolute path of node-modules folder
```

should return : **/home/projects/test-project/node-modules** even though npak is installed globally

How do I get at the absolute path of the local 'node-modules' folder regardless of what the cwd is from a globally installed package?

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](https://github.com/callumacrae/find-node-modules)?

Comment: @robertklep that'll work...if you set it as an answer I'll mark it answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some useful modules, like [`find-node-modules`](https://github.com/callumacrae/find-node-modules), that can help you with such a task.

Answer (score 0):

`__dirname` gives the path of the executing script.

Comment: the executing script is a globally installed nodule...but i need the path to the local 'node_modules' folder